# What is the technique I should use here $\phi_{1}(x)=e^{x^{2}}, y^{\prime \prime}-4 x y^{\prime}+\left(4 x^{2}-2\right) y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am asking to solve this differential equation while I am given one of its solutions, I am not familliar with this kind of equation, it reminds me ODE but the coeficciant are constants so I will not be able to use the charachteristic polynomial.

$$\phi_{1}(x)=e^{x^{2}}, \quad y^{\prime \prime}-4 x y^{\prime}+\left(4 x^{2}-2\right) y=0$$

Comment: Reduce the order substitute $y=ve^{x^2}$

Comment: is $v$ constant or function? can you explain what is the logic behind that?

Comment: V is a function of x I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments the given solution suggests the substitution
$$y=ue^{x^2}$$
which gives
$$y'=(2xu+u')e^{x^2}$$
$$y''=((2+4x^2)u+4xu'+u'')e^{x^2}$$
and hence the original equation is equivalent to
$$((2+4x^2)u+4xu'+u'')e^{x^2}-4x(2xu+u')e^{x^2}+(4x^2-2)ue^{x^2}=0$$
which reduces significantly to
$$u''=0\implies y=(C_1+C_2x)e^{x^2}$$

Comment: I do not understand how $u''=0$ ?

Comment: @Sagugever Divide by $e^{x^2}\ne0$ and every other term cancels when you expand. It's is equivalent to the original equation.

Comment: Ok now I understand why $u''=0$ but I still do not understand how does it help me?  I would like if can explain $u''=0\implies y=(C_1+C_2x)e^{x^2}$

Comment: The only function with second derivative equal to zero is a linear polynomial i.e. $u=C_1+C_2x$ for some constants $C_1,C_2$. Then I just used $y=ue^{x^2}$ by definition.

Comment: understood, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\phi_{1}(x)=e^{x^{2}}, \quad y^{\prime \prime}-4 x y^{\prime}+\left(4 x^{2}-2\right) y=0$$
You are given one of the two solutions. You can reduce the order so you will have a first order differential equation. Substitute in the equation :
$$y=v(x)e^{x^2}$$
$$y'=(v'(x)+2xv(x))e^{x^2}$$
$$y''=v''(x)e^{x^2}+4xv'(x)e^{x^2}+v(x)e^{x^2}(2+4x^2)$$
Plug $y,y',y''$ in the original differential equation then you get an equation in $v$ of first order. Then  solve that first order linear differential equation.
$$v''(x)e^{x^2}=0  \implies v''(x)=0$$
Integrate twice.

Comment: so now I should solve the equation : $y'=v'(x)e^{x^2}+2xv(x)e^{x^2}$?

Comment: No you have to plug that in the original DE @Sagigever